# Spark 2.2.0: Log4J configured before logger is instantiated

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, logging, log4j

I have a project using custom log4j property files and levels that worked in Spark versions 2.0.2 or older.  An upgrade to Spark 2.2.0 was needed to resolve some performance issues, but it breaks the log4j components.

The log4j properties file makes references to a system property "current.date", as well as a custom log level class in the package:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file,file2
log4j.logger.com.package.project.PROJECTDriver=PROJECT#com.package.project.PROJECTLogLevel,file3

log4j.appender.file3=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file3.File=../../../../project/log/PROJECTUserLog_${current.date}.log
log4j.appender.file3.Append=false
log4j.appender.file3.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.file3.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file3.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file3.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file3.threshold=PROJECT#com.package.project.PROJECTLogLevel
log4j.appender.file3.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.file3.filter.filter1.levelMax=INFO
```

The references are declared in the code prior to instantiating the log4j logger:

```
val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
System.out.println("Starting Project Driver")
System.setProperty("current.date", dateFormat.format(new Date()))
var log: Logger = LogManager.getLogger("com.package.project.PROJECTDriver")
```

After upgrading to Spark 2.2.0, Log4j started to complain that it could not find the custom log level class. It was also not appending the current.date value, just leaving it blank.

After some digging around and playing with log4j debug mode, I found that in Spark 2.2.0, log4j was being configured before the project code was ran.  In the previous Spark versions, the debug output looks like this:

```
Starting Project Driver
log4j: *log4j configuration steps, going through the properties file*
```

In Spark 2.2.0, the order is reversed:

```
log4j: *log4j configuration steps, going through the properties file*
Starting Project Driver
```

I couldn't find any notes on this change in Spark 2.2.0.  Is there any way to fix log4j so that configuration starts when the logger is called?

Comment: Are u using `file3` appender? Or do you want to use it? b/c u have `log4j.rootLogger=INFO,file,file2` - there isn't `file3`.

Comment: file3 is using a custom log level within the project:
    log4j.logger.com.package.project.PROJECTDriver=PROJECT#com.package.project.PROJECTLogLevel,file3